# Jersey serializes character value to ASCII equivalent numeric string

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I am implementing simple RESTful webservice using Jersey API. My server project is hosted on Apache Tomcat ver 6.0 and it contains **asm-3.0.jar**, **jersey-bundle-1.9.1.jar** and **jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar**.

I have two resource classes. One is `UserItemsResource` which is intended to represent collection of `UserItem` objects. The other one is `UserItemResource` which represents a single `UserItem` resource.

Below is code for `UserItemsResource` class:

```
@Path("/useritems")
public class UserItemsResource {

    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Context
    Request request;

    @Path("{userId}")
    public UserItemResource getUserItemResource(@PathParam("userId") long userId) {
        return new UserItemResource(uriInfo, request, userId);
    }
}
```

The `UserItemResource` class:

```
public class UserItemResource {
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Context
    Request request;

    private long userId;

    public UserItemResource(UriInfo uriInfo, Request request, long userId) {
        this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
        this.request = request;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public UserItem getUserItem() {
        return new UserItem(userId, 'M', "Pawan");
    }
}
```

And the `UserItem` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class UserItem {
    private long userId;
    private char sex;
    private String displayName;

    public UserItem() {

    }

    public UserItem(long userId, char sex, String displayName) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public char getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setSex(char sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

When I invoke the resource (like `/useritems/101`), I am getting following response from server.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 11:30:35 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

{
  "displayName": "Pawan",
  "sex": "77",
  "userId": "101"
}
```

You can see that the value for **"sex"** attribute is generated as **"77"**, which is ASCII equivalent of character 'M'. I believe this should come as "M" only, so that my client code can successfully parse it back to 'M'. I am using **Jackson** API (ver 2.0.2) to parse the json entity in the server response back to object of UserItem class.

Am I missing something? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey supports few JSON notations and each one of them has a slightly different convention on how the resulting JSON should look like. You can see the difference between notations in this [JavaDoc](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9.1/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/json/JSONConfiguration.Notation.html). The default one is `MAPPED` which put quotes around numbers in JSON output as you've already found out.

There are two things you can do:

- turn on the [Jackson POJO support](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.pojo.approach.section) which uses the Jackson library to create JSON output (maybe this would be a better option if you're using Jackson on the client side as well). There is also an example how to use it - [JacksonJsonProvider](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/jersey/samples/jacksonjsonprovider).
- use `NATURAL` JSON notation which handles numbers as you'd expect. To do this you need to provide a custom [ContextResolver](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) and register it in your application. Examples how to achieve this can be found in [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/) ([JSON Support - Configuration Options](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e928)) or in one of the samples [json-from-jaxb](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/jersey/samples/json-from-jaxb) (see [JAXBContextResolver](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/jersey/samples/json-from-jaxb/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/jsonfromjaxb/config/JAXBContextResolver.java)).

Comment: Perfect. I followed the first approach you mentioned since, my client project uses Jackson to parse JSON strings. I have added Jackson libraries to server classpath and modified web.xml to set init-param 'com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature' to true. Now this is working absolutely fine.

Thanks for pointers/references you have shared in your answer.