# JSON Response behaviour on browser

Tags: json, jersey

I am trying to count the number of elements inside the JSONArray and to print the RESPONSE in json form on the browser.

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(somestring_withjsonarray);
objList.setCount(ja.length());
```

This gives the the correct number of elements inside the array but I wonder why does it show the output on the browser as "count": "3" (with double quotes), and not "count": 3 (since count is of type int).

Why is it so?

Comment: More detail, please. We have no idea what `objList` is, nor how you're serializing it to JSON.

Comment: objList is the JSON object class which has int count declared with get and set method. objList is returned from a method with annotations @GET
and @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Comment: What JAXB serializer are you using? Have you tried using Jackson? It's overall much better-behaved.

Comment: Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to a similar question [Jersey serializes character value to ASCII equivalent numeric string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13051991/290799).